# How to create a QuickSight histogram visualization using start and end date fields? (GANTT chart)

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I plan on displaying the availability of my data by having the start and end date on the x-axis and the type of data on the y-axis which can be drilled into.

How would I be able to do this? I'm only able to add 2 fields to the histogram visual (x and y axis)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

- Calculate min(start dates)
- Calculate difference between min(start date) and start date in days
- Calculate difference between start date and end date in days

Use a horizontal stacked bar chart visual with bar 1 as the gap between the difference between min(start date) and start date. Match the color of this bar with the background color. Have bar 2 as a different color which displays the difference in days between the start and end dates.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to have the dates appear on the x-axis, so it would be better to hide the axis entirely.

In order to view the start and end dates associated with a bar, add these values in the tooltips.